# RTMP to WebRTC? Does it make sense?

Tags: video-streaming, webrtc, html5-video, rtmp

I have found [this article](https://antmedia.io/rtmp-to-webrtc-migration-rtmp-is-dying/). According to the article WebRTC is the only solution for ultra low latency streaming as a RTMP alternative. What do you think about that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [send nginx rtmp fragments to WebRTC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66183141/send-nginx-rtmp-fragments-to-webrtc)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you're streaming to the web, WebRTC is the only real low latency option.

You can get reasonably low latency out of HTTP progressive streams.  (Equivalent latency to what you would get out of RTMP, ~500ms.)  Sadly, none of the CDNs will support it, so we're stuck with HLS and DASH, and their "low latency" variants, unless you DIY the whole stack.